# Error converting PEM to PPK using PUTTYgen

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, putty, amazon-iam

This generate three files **rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem**.

I want to convert this file into ppk format.

For this I am using PUTTYGEN.

When i load rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem file then this gives me error

```
couldn't load private key (file does not begin with openssh key header)
```

PEM contains multiple lines of -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Example-

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: did you try removing the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  and -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: There are multiple such lines in the .pem file. should i remove all?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load a public key with intermediate certificates and maybe the CA cert (the public key chain) and you should be loading the single private key into puttygen to generate a private key ppk.

What are you trying to achieve with the ppk, i.e. what is the goal that requires a ppk file?

Update: You can't SSH directly onto the Linux instance of RDS, only ssh DB connections.

You can access RDS MySQL logs via the AWS console, AWS CLI and also the API and SDKs. I suggest you use the CLI, which you can run in Powershell or cmd instead of using putty.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html

Comment: I'm trying to connect to AWS Sandbox instance to check my MySQL log files from PUTTY SSH

Comment: Are you running MySQL in RDS? Those public keys are for SSH connections to RDS from Linux applications/clients. If you want to connect to MySQL over SSH from windows then you can get the public key already in the correct format from https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.p7b

Comment: yes im running MySQL in RDS. I want to connect to the linux Command line from PUTTY. hence im trying to convert the pem to ppk and i get this error.

`couldn't load private key (file does not begin with openssh key header)`

Comment: You cannot connect to the Linux shell/command line for an RDS instance. AWS manages the Linux bit and allows connections to MySQL over ssh but not onto the command line, you are confusing RDS access with EC2. Please see this link for how to access RDS MySQL logs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html

Comment: Thank you @NHol. I did got confused with RDS and EC2